# Can't toggle class from Font Awesome in a treeview

Tags: jquery, html, treeview, font-awesome

The code I used for my treeview is this:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/quotboottreequot-treeview-for-bootstrap

I changed the code that references to the glyphicons a little bit to this

```
branch.prepend("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
            branch.addClass('tree-branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');

                    icon.toggleClass("fa fa-chevron-circle-down");
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();
                }
            })
```

So I basically just changed the classes.
Now when I click on the circle-right, there is no cirlce-down.
As far as i'm aware, there might be a problem with the space between the 2 fa's?

Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're also toggling the "fa" class, which is needed by Font Awesome.

I recommend toggling both classes, "fa-chevron-circle-down" and "fa-chevron-circle-right", so that it doesn't get both classes at once.

```js
var icon = $('#test');
icon.on('click', function() {
  icon.toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-right fa-chevron-circle-down");
});
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right' id="test"></i>
```

Comment: Right now my code looks like this: `branch.prepend("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
    branch.addClass('tree-branch');
    branch.on('click', function (e) {
     if (this == e.target) {
      var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
      
      icon.toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-right fa-chevron-circle-down");
      $(this).children().children().toggle();
     }
    }) `

The circle-down button still goes into hiding after clicking it though. He's not visible at all.

Comment: Can you create a working example to help demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Here is a video where you can see the problem: https://imgur.com/a/MXqtBda

Comment: I'll need to see your code in order to troubleshoot. Maybe "circle-down" is not in your icon set?

Answer (score 0):

Nigel please note that in sample which you have provided they are toggling:

```
icon.toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right");
```

So you should toggle:

```
icon.toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-right fa-chevron-circle-down");
```